# How to provide spring boot application.yml property values coming from files

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

Is there a way for providing spring boot properties value text from file? I tried something like below but it's not working.

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-secret: classpath:./secrets/google-client-secret.txt
            client-id: classpath:./secrets/google-client-id.txt
```

The secrets folder is created inside resources folder

Comment: It's not possible this way. To answer this question I would like to know why you want to put these values in a separate file. Why don't you put them directly in your spring boot properties?

Comment: I can add secrets folder to git ignore file so that these files will not be push to repository . I do not want to check in these secrets values to git repo

Answer (score 4):

The way you're implementing this is not possible. There are several other ways to implement [externalized configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config) though.

#### Using environment variables

In your IDE you can configure environment variables. If the names of the environment variables match the name of the property, you can remove the parameters from `application.yml`. For example:

```sh
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=actual-secret
SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=actual-id
```

You can also name your environment variables differently. For example:

```sh
GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET=actual-secret
GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID=actual-id
```

In that case, you have to change your `application.yml` to this:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
```

#### Using a separate YAML file

Another possibility is to create a file called `secrets.yml`, make it contain your actual values and put it in `.gitignore`. This solution is the closest to what you want.

For example, in `secrets.yml` you can put:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-secret: actual-secret
            client-id: actual-id
```

Now you can load it by using the `--spring.config.additional-location` VM argument (also configurable in your IDE):

```
java -jar myapp.jar --spring.config.additional-location=classpath:secrets.yml
```

#### Using VM arguments

Speaking of VM arguments, you can also pass the properties themselves as VM arguments.

For example:

```sh
java \
  -jar myapp.jar \
  -Dspring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-id=actual-id \
  -Dspring.security.oauth2.client.registration.google.client-secret=actual-secret
```

Like with the environment variables, you can use shorter VM arguments and reference them in `application.yml`. For example by using `-Dgoogle.client-id=actual-id` and putting `${google.client-id}` in your `application.yml`.

---

There are several other ways of providing externalized configuration, so I suggest you read the documentation I linked earlier.

Comment: Hi, I think it is possible https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/resources/application.yml 
 but for me it is failing

Comment: @Rajeev No, that's because the code that using those `jwt.private.key`  and `jwt.public.key` properties is expecting, that doesn't mean that all properties support them.

Comment: I'm not aware of this. Thank you @g00glen00b

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that it is not possible to do that.

What I recommend you tho is to use environment variables to achieve that:

```yaml
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          google:
            client-secret: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET}
            client-id: ${GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID}
```

This way the secrets will be tied to the environment and not into the yml file.

Comment: Hi, I think it is possible https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-samples/blob/main/servlet/spring-boot/java/jwt/login/src/main/resources/application.yml but for me it is failing

Comment: why introduce a _new_ env variable `GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET`, when `SPRING_SECURITY_OAUTH2_CLIENT_REGISTRATION_GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET` is already supported by Springs relaxed binding? To make it shorter, I guess, right?

Comment: With the longer env variable, you don't need the entry in `application.yml`. I like to be more explicit with my properties, having it only in the env makes it find for users to find it.